# Right hand system $3 \times 3$ determinant

Tags: vectors

My text book says the $3 \times 3$ determinant will be positive if and only vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ make up a right hand system. What does it mean that they make up a right hand system?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule

Answer (score 0):

"The rule which determines the orientation of the cross product $u×v$. The right-hand rule states that the orientation of the vectors' cross product is determined by placing u and v tail-to-tail, flattening the right hand, extending it in the direction of u, and then curling the fingers in the direction that the angle v makes with u. The thumb then points in the direction of $u×v$."

[image]

see [Right-Hand Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Right-HandRule.html)

Answer (score 0):

It means that $\vec{u}$ sees from its head that $\vec{v}$ needs to rotate counterclockwise in the plane $(\vec{v}, \vec{w})$ to overlap $\vec{w}$ when using the least angle between the two possible.